# Complicated sqlite query and use of arrays

Tags: sqlite, sorting

I have two tables, "logs", and "sessions". A log has a logID, logName, logDateTime, and sessionID. A session has a sessionID and sessionName.

A log does not need to be part of a session, but it CAN be. If it it NOT part of a session, the field logs.sessionID is NULL. If it IS part of a session, the associated sessionID is in logs.sessionID and it correlates with the sessions table.

**The goal:**
This is part of my iphone application, developed using titanium studio. I need to create a tableview in which each log is a row, EXCEPT for when there are multiple logs in a session. In that case, a row with the session name is created, and a label with the session's logNames is added to the sessionRow. The tableview rows need to be ordered by datetime, and the datetime of a given session is calculated by the most recent of it's logs. So to visualize it as a tableview...

---

12-12-12  logName1

---

12-11-12 logName2

---

sessionName

logName3, logName4, logName5

---

12-10-12 logName6

---

sessionName2

logName7, logName8, logName9

---

**The problem:** I'm not quite sure how to handle this from a query/sort perspective. I've thought of many ideas but they all seem to have an issue. I am NOT looking for help on building the UI of this tableview, simply a solution of handling the data.

**Works in progress:**

```
**OPTION 1:**

var rowArray=[];
var ignoreArray=[];

var rows = select logID, logName, logDateTime, logs.sessionID, sessionName
           FROM logs, sessions WHERE logs.sessionID=sessions.sessionID OR
           logs.sessionID IS NULL ORDER BY logDateTime DESC, logs.sessionID;

while(rows.isValidRow()){
    var logSessionID = rows.fieldByName('sessionID');

    if(logSessionID){//if the current log is part of a session
        //1. check ignoreArray to see if this session has
             already been created. If not, continue steps 2-4.
        //2. create a tableview row with the sessionName
        //3. loop through all rows, and add the logName to the row created above
             ONLY when it contains the current sessionID
        //4. add session row to rowArray
        //5. put current sessionID into ignoreArray, so that there won't be
             duplicate session rows.
    }else{
        //1. create a regular log row, as it is not part of a session
        //2. add log row to rowArray
    }

    rows.next();
}

//everything is complete, set the array of data to the tableview
tableview.setData(rowArray);
```

My concerns/questions with option 1:

1. Is it terribly inefficient due to the loop through ALL rows every time I hit a new session
2. Will it be slow with hundreds, if not thousands of logs?
3. How can I loop through all rows WHILE I am in the middle of looping through all rows (nested)?

   **OPTION 2:**

   ```
   var presortArray=[];

   var logs = select * from logs WHERE sessionID IS NULL;
   var sessionlogs = select * from logs WHERE sessionID IS NOT NULL;
   var sessions = select * from sessions;

   while(logs.isValidRow()){
       //1. create log row, push to presortArray;
   };
   while(sessions.isValidRow()){
       //1. create session row
       //2. loop through sessionlogs, adding each to the session row
            that contains the current sessionID. Make sure the session
            Row gets a custom date field for future array sorting
       //3. push session row to presortArray
   };

   //all rows are now in presortArray.
   var sortArray = //find a way to sort the rows in presortArray based on datetime

   tableview.setData(sortArray);
   ```

My concerns/questions with option 2:

1. Is it going to be slow to use some form of array sorting, based on a custom field of each object in the array?
2. Can I loop through "sessionLogs" many times, is there a way to set it back to the first row each time I loop?

**MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION: Now that I have made a serious effort to explain, and hopefully not overexplain, my goal and my work in progress. Is there a much simpler way to do this, that I have not yet realized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this example data:

```
CREATE TABLE logs(logID, logName, logDateTime, sessionID);
CREATE TABLE sessions(sessionID, sessionName);
INSERT INTO sessions VALUES (1, 'sessionName'), (2, 'sessionName2');
INSERT INTO logs VALUES (1, 'logName1', '2012-12-12', NULL),
                        (2, 'logName2', '2012-11-12', NULL),
                        (3, 'logName3', '2012-11-01', 1),
                        (4, 'logName4', '2012-11-02', 1),
                        (5, 'logName5', '2012-11-03', 1),
                        (6, 'logName6', '2012-10-12', NULL),
                        (7, 'logName7', '2012-10-01', 2),
                        (8, 'logName8', '2012-10-02', 2),
                        (9, 'logName9', '2012-10-03', 2);
```

the following query:

```
SELECT logID,
       NULL AS sessionID,
       logDateTime,
       logName,
       NULL AS NamesInRandomOrder
FROM logs
WHERE sessionID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,
       sessions.sessionID,
       MAX(logDateTime),
       sessionName,
       group_concat(logName)
FROM logs JOIN sessions ON logs.sessionID = sessions.sessionID
GROUP BY sessions.sessionID

ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

will give this output:

```
logID  sessionID  logDateTime  logName       NamesInRandomOrder
-----  ---------  -----------  ------------  --------------------------
1                 2012-12-12   logName1
2                 2012-11-12   logName2
       1          2012-11-03   sessionName   logName3,logName4,logName5
6                 2012-10-12   logName6
       2          2012-10-03   sessionName2  logName7,logName8,logName9
```

---

If you want the `logName`s to be ordered, you could use this query:

```
SELECT logID,
       sessions.sessionID,
       logDateTime,
       sessionName,
       logName
FROM logs LEFT JOIN sessions ON logs.sessionID = sessions.sessionID
ORDER BY logDateTime DESC
```

which would give you this output:

```
logID  sessionID  logDateTime  sessionName   logName
-----  ---------  -----------  ------------  --------
1                 2012-12-12                 logName1
2                 2012-11-12                 logName2
5      1          2012-11-03   sessionName   logName5
4      1          2012-11-02   sessionName   logName4
3      1          2012-11-01   sessionName   logName3
6                 2012-10-12                 logName6
9      2          2012-10-03   sessionName2  logName9
8      2          2012-10-02   sessionName2  logName8
7      2          2012-10-01   sessionName2  logName7
```

This would require you to check in your code when you have reached the end of the list of the logs for one session.

Comment: Well that is quite amazing! If you don't mind me inquiring about some things regarding your answer...

Is it possible to order the logNames in a session by logDateTime?

Is it possible to loop through NamesInRandomOrder, when I get to that row?

Comment: [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) returns the elements in arbitrary order, and returns a single string. You would have to split and order them in your code.

Comment: found a way to order by logDateTime, just figured I would share:
    group_concat(logName order by logDateTime DESC)

Thanks for all of your help